# Not able to take key values to return as dictionary from Core data fetch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am saving some key values to Profile entity. But, I am trying to fetch and returning as dictionary to take as key values to main class.

```
static func fetchProfile) -> [String: Any]? {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let profileFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: AccountinfoKeyConstant.Entity_Profile)
    var fetchedObjects: [String: Any]?

    var entityDescription: NSEntityDescription? = nil
    entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: AccountinfoKeyConstant.Entity_Profile, in: context)
    profileFetch.entity = entityDescription
    do {
        let objects = try context.fetch(profileFetch)
        print("objects \(objects)")
        fetchedObjects = objects as [String: Any]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetched. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    return fetchedObjects

}
```

In above code I am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to type '[String : Any]' in coercion

for this line `fetchedObjects = objects as [String: Any]`

Any suggestions? How to take only dictionary to return it into main class?

Output is:

```
objects [<Profile: 0x6000026c3ca0> (entity: Profile; id: 0x8d815a305b375e8d <x-coredata://F92995FE-578E-48EB-AA07-242ECBBBBFE4/Profile/p20>; data: {
     birthdate = "04/22/2020";
     email = "example@test.com";
    "family_name" = myName;
    gender = " ";
    "given_name" = myName123;
    name = name123;
})]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a dictionary you have to specify the generic `NSFetchRequest` as `NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>` and also to add the `dictionaryResultType`.

Nevertheless fetching objects returns **always** an non-optional array.

Further making the method `throw` reduces the code considerably.

```
static func fetchProfile() -> [[String: Any]] throws {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let profileFetch : NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: AccountinfoKeyConstant.Entity_Profile)
    profileFetch.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

    return try context.fetch(profileFetch) as! [[String:Any]]

}
```

If there is only one record in the entity return the first item

```
static func fetchProfile() -> [String: Any] throws {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let profileFetch : NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: AccountinfoKeyConstant.Entity_Profile)
    profileFetch.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    let result = try context.fetch(profileFetch) as! [[String:Any]]
    return result.first ?? [:]

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for quick response and suggestions @Vadian, But, Errors are thrown from here are not handled error throwing for second method,         let result = try context.fetch(profileFetch) as! [[String:Any]]

Comment: I tried this but, crashing,  var result =  [[String:Any]]()
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try context.fetch(profileFetch) as! [String: Any]
            result = [jsonData]
            print("result \(result)")
            //all fine with jsonData here
        } catch {
            //handle error
            print(error)
        }

Comment: I fixed the issue along with your code, Thank you so much and I am upvoting your answer and accepting too @Vadian